# Convert currencies in real time using jQuery and or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, currency

http://jsfiddle.net/6mMUs/

I want to have live currency rate inputs for Euros, Dollars and Pounds.

```
<input type="text" id="eurorate" style="margin-bottom:15px;"> Euros <br />
<input type="text" id="dollarrate" style="margin-bottom:15px;"> Dollars <br />
<input type="text" id="poundrate" style="margin-bottom:15px;"> Pounds
```

What's the proper way of assigning a multiplier to each of these 3 currencies and have them respond to change in ANY of the inputs in real time?

for example, if a dollar is 0.75 euros and it is 0.60 Pounds, when I enter '1' in the dollar field, the other fields should show the correct values when converted to the other currencies.

I tried doing this with setInterval but it is not truly real time, I want to know what's the proper alternative using keyup or something like that.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `onkeyup` event on your input fields, and when the event fires you update the other ones.

Comment: should it be the same function for all inputs?

Comment: Yes, however the function should include a check to see which input the event is coming from, and only update the other ones.

Comment: Would this work? 
onKeyUp="updateRates(this)" 
and then 
function updateRates(inputid) {

}

Comment: Sorry, should have been  onKeyUp="updateRates(this.id)" and then function updateRates(inputid) { }

Comment: Eh... I'd just pass `this`, personally.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Method to Covert Currency

```html
            <html>
        <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
         <script>
        function changeTo(toType){
        
          
          if(toType=="Pound")
                cvrate = 0.86;
          else
                cvrate = 0.78;      
                
                        
          $(".currency_change").each(function (index, element) {
               var og_val  = $(this).data("og-value");
               var cvd_val = (og_val*cvrate).toFixed(2);
               return $(this).html(cvd_val);  
            });
            }
        </script>  
        
        </head>
        <body>
        <br /><span class="currency_change" data-og-value="1254">1254</span>
        <br /><span class="currency_change" data-og-value="145">145</span>
        <br /><span class="currency_change" data-og-value="54">54</span>
        <br /><span class="currency_change" data-og-value="254">254</span>
        <br /><span class="currency_change" data-og-value="147">147</span><br />
        <button onClick="changeTo('Pound');">Conver To Pound</button>
        <button onClick="changeTo('Euro');">Conver To Euro</button>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52040430/1324) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)