# Trying to get currency converter to work using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, converters, currency

I'm working on a project using jQuery to make a currency converter. I'm getting the currency info from an api service and loading it up in a table with multiple currencies. After which, I want to be able to enter a number in one input and make the other inputs produce the correct currency according to the entered input.

As you can see in the following code, I'm trying to make the keyup function work on everything but the input of which the numbers are being entered at that moment. 
My output result from the function is also incorrect.

If anyone can point out the very obvious mistake I'm making here that would be very helpful!

**JS:**

```
function parseCurrency(data) {
var container = $('.currency-data');

var iskInput = $('<tr>' +'<td>' + '<strong>ISK</strong>' + 
    '</td> ' + '<td>' + 'Íslensk króna' + 
    '</td>' + '<td></td>' + '<td>' + '1' + '</td>' + 
    '<td>' + '<input value="1000" class="input-value"></input>' + '</td>' + 
    '</tr>'); 
iskInput.prependTo(container);

$.each(data.results, function (key, currency){
    var row = [];
    row = $('<tr></tr>');
    row.append('<td>' + '<strong>' + currency.shortName + '</strong>' + '</td>');
    row.append('<td>' + currency.longName + '</td>');
    row.append('<td>' + currency.changeCur + '</td>');
    row.append('<td>' + currency.value + '</td>');
    var input = $('<input class="input-value"></input>');
    input.val((1000/currency.value).toFixed(2));
    var td = $('<td></td>');
    input.appendTo(td);
    td.appendTo(row);
    container.append(row);
})
var inputValue = $('.input-value');
var inputActive = $('.input-value:focus')

$.each(data.results, function (key, currency) {
    inputValue.not(inputActive).keyup( function () {
        inputValue.val((inputValue.val()/currency.value ).toFixed(2));
    });
})
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<form name="converter"></div>
        <h4>Collecting data from: <a href="" class="m5">m5</a> <a href=""      class="arion">A bank</a> <a href="" class="lb">Lb</a></h4>
        <div>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Obj1</th>
                        <th>Obj2</th>
                        <th>Obj3</th>
                        <th>Obj4</th>
                        <th>Obj5</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="currency-data">
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="loader lead" style="display:none;">Loading...</div>         
        </form>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a working example? it is hard to see exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: binding input keyup in loop is going to compound event handlers and last event handler will prevail. You are binding nuerous handlers to each element, not targeting the one you want in each iteration

Comment: You seem to describe a currency conversion table which will convert a value entered in any currency to all other currencies present in the table. But for each currency, you know only the exchange rate to/from Íslensk Króna. Therefore you have two parts to your problem: (a) devising a generalised formula that will allow any-to-any conversion based on the data you have; (b) coding that generalised formula. BTW - once you have your head round it, it's actually very simple.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit strange for me, because you select all the input field which are NOT focused, and in the keyup eventhandler you just work with the inputValue variable, which contains the focused input element too. By the way, you shouldn't iterate two times on the data.results. As charlietfl commented before it does not make any sense to put the bindings to the iteration. That's a big mistake also.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Method

```html
            <html>
        <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
         <script>
        function changeTo(toType){
        
          
          if(toType=="Pound")
                cvrate = 0.86;
          else
                cvrate = 0.78;      
                
                        
          $(".currency_change").each(function (index, element) {
               var og_val  = $(this).data("og-value");
               var cvd_val = (og_val*cvrate).toFixed(2);
               return $(this).html(cvd_val);  
            });
            }
        </script>  
        
        </head>
        <body>
        <br /><span class="currency_change" data-og-value="1254">1254</span>
        <br /><span class="currency_change" data-og-value="145">145</span>
        <br /><span class="currency_change" data-og-value="54">54</span>
        <br /><span class="currency_change" data-og-value="254">254</span>
        <br /><span class="currency_change" data-og-value="147">147</span><br />
        <button onClick="changeTo('Pound');">Conver To Pound</button>
        <button onClick="changeTo('Euro');">Conver To Euro</button>
        </body>
        </html>
```